# How to print the results of a breadth first transversal given this code (Java)

Tags: java, depth, directed-graph

How do I print out the results of a breadth-first transversal using the example code from GitHub? where should I put the Main method?
Thanks,
here's the code link for the first class:
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/data-structures/src/main/java/com/baeldung/graph/Graph.java
and here's the code:

```
    package com.baeldung.graph;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    
    public class Graph {
        private Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjVertices;
    
        Graph() {
        this.adjVertices = new HashMap<Vertex, List<Vertex>>();
    }

    void addVertex(String label) {
        adjVertices.putIfAbsent(new Vertex(label), new ArrayList<>());
    }

    void removeVertex(String label) {
        Vertex v = new Vertex(label);
        adjVertices.values().stream().forEach(e -> e.remove(v));
        adjVertices.remove(new Vertex(label));
    }

    void addEdge(String label1, String label2) {
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
        adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2);
        adjVertices.get(v2).add(v1);
    }

    void removeEdge(String label1, String label2) {
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
        List<Vertex> eV1 = adjVertices.get(v1);
        List<Vertex> eV2 = adjVertices.get(v2);
        if (eV1 != null)
            eV1.remove(v2);
        if (eV2 != null)
            eV2.remove(v1);
    }

    List<Vertex> getAdjVertices(String label) {
        return adjVertices.get(new Vertex(label));
    }
    
    String printGraph() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(Vertex v : adjVertices.keySet()) {
            sb.append(v);
            sb.append(adjVertices.get(v));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    class Vertex {
        String label;
        Vertex(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            result = prime * result + ((label == null) ? 0 : label.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
            if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
                return false;
            if (label == null) {
                if (other.label != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!label.equals(other.label))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return label;
        }


        private Graph getOuterType() {
            return Graph.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the link for the second class:
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/data-structures/src/main/java/com/baeldung/graph/GraphTraversal.java
and here's the code:

```
    package com.baeldung.graph;
    
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Queue;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Stack;
    
    import com.baeldung.graph.Graph.Vertex;
    
    public class GraphTraversal {
        static Set<String> depthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, String root) {
            Set<String> visited = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
            stack.push(root);
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                String vertex = stack.pop();
                if (!visited.contains(vertex)) {
                    visited.add(vertex);
                    for (Vertex v : graph.getAdjVertices(vertex)) {              
                        stack.push(v.label);
                    }
                }
            }
            return visited;
        }
    
        static Set<String> breadthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, String root) {
            Set<String> visited = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
            queue.add(root);
            visited.add(root);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                String vertex = queue.poll();
                for (Vertex v : graph.getAdjVertices(vertex)) {
                    if (!visited.contains(v.label)) {
                        visited.add(v.label);
                        queue.add(v.label);
                    }
                }
            }
            return visited;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to put a programming language(in this case java) as a tag because many people search for language-tags and will not see your question.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov added, thank you

Comment: I tried adding the main method in the graph.java class and created the graph in the main method  but I get null pointer exceptions when i try to add vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're trying to print a `Graph` and aren't sure where to put the `main()` method. You can simply put it in the graph class if you're just testing the code, but if you're trying to build a project using this class, you might want to make a different class to store the `main()` method.

Printing is straightforward since they give a `Set<String>`. Just add the following line before the method returns the visited nodes. This converts the visited nodes list to a string.

```
System.out.println(visited.toString());
```

You can test it with the following code:

```
static Graph createGraph() {
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    graph.addVertex("Bob");
    graph.addVertex("Alice");
    graph.addVertex("Mark");
    graph.addVertex("Rob");
    graph.addVertex("Maria");
    graph.addEdge("Bob", "Alice");
    graph.addEdge("Bob", "Rob");
    graph.addEdge("Alice", "Mark");
    graph.addEdge("Rob", "Mark");
    graph.addEdge("Alice", "Maria");
    graph.addEdge("Rob", "Maria");
    return graph;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph graph = createGraph();
    GraphTraversal.breadthFirstTraversal(graph, "Bob");
}
```

Which gives:

```
[Bob, Alice, Rob, Mark, Maria]
```

Additionally, you commented that you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to add vertices. There isn't enough information to figure out why you get the exception, but it may be helpful for you to check the unit tests, to figure out how to make use of the class. The unit tests are [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/data-structures/src/test/java/com/baeldung/graph/GraphUnitTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

This example is given here
https://www.baeldung.com/java-graphs

The code is declaring `adjVertices` but not actually creating it. You need to add below instead to fix the nullpointer exception.

```
private Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjVertices = new HashMap<Vertex, List<Vertex>>();
```